# Checkpointing using EAsimple and Deap

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm, checkpoint, deap

My issue involves checkpointing. I have my genetic algorithm code running well using eaSimple, but I need to run tests and evaluation on large population sizes (1000+) with many generations (50+). Because I am working remotely my connections to the host will time out after 12 hours. These larger tests can run for longer than this time, and I end up losing my spot in the algorithm. I attempted to create a checkpoint, but it will only create a checkpoint after all generations have run. Is there a way to checkpoint using EaSimple, or do I have to write my own genetic algorithm to include a manual checkpointing system?

according to the deap manual I can't checkpoint with included algorithms, Is there a way around this?
https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/advanced/checkpoint.html

Thank you

Comment: Also, not a new contributor, My old account was a work account that I no longer have access to.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you tried to do? The example you linked seems to pickle every NFREQ generations, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is very late answer, but hopefully this maybe useful for new comers like myself. You can edit 'eaSimple' function inside 'algorithms' by adding two arguments (FREQ and chkpoints_dir) and add these lines to the end:

```
def eaSimple(population, toolbox, cxpb, mutpb, ngen, stats=None,
         halloffame=None, verbose=__debug__, FREQ=None, chkpoints_dir=None):

    """
    eaSimple code
    """

    if gen % FREQ == 0:
        # Fill the dictionary using the dict(key=value[, ...]) constructor
        cp = dict(population=population, generation=gen, halloffame=halloffame,
                      logbook=logbook, rndstate=random.getstate())
        
        # saving
        import os
        import pickle
        fname = os.path.join(chkpoints_dir, f"checkpoint_{str(gen)}.pkl")
        with open(fname, "wb") as cp_file:
            pickle.dump(cp, cp_file)
```